# React + Vite: different stylesheet for mobile and desktop views

Tags: reactjs, typescript, responsive, vite

I have a React + Vite project, and I am importing in *main.tsx* the stylesheet as follows. It contains all desktop SCSS-files.

```
// main.tsx
import './styles/_main.scss';
```

I also use the react-device-detect plugin to check the device the user is currently on:

```
// main.tsx
import { BrowserView, MobileView } from 'react-device-detect';
```

On mobile devices, I would like to load a *_main-mobile.scss* in stead of the main SCSS file, because the mobile website is quite different. Is there a preferred way to do that efficiently?

Comment: Why not use css media queries? Dynamically importing css is not a good idea for client side rendered websites since they bundle everything at build time and it would create an unstyled state until the css is loaded.